# Push data from Servlet to webpage

Tags: java, servlets

Ok .. I think this question is dumb but its something I need so asking.

I have a servlet that checks health status of about 20-50 servers depending on situations.

I am trying to reduce the time to as low as possible but it still takes me 15-20 seconds to respond.

I am printing stuff on console for my satisfaction that the servlet isnt stuch but a user cant see that.

Is there any way I could print data on the requesting or a new page so that user knows that server isnt stuck - I dont wanna pass the request as there is still some processing to do.

I just want to print like I do in console. I checked [System.setOut(PrintStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) but this also caries the data only after I pass request dispatcher - not good for me.

I am sorry if its a dumb question. I couldn't find a solution for my problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I am currently displaying a picture that says loading. But even if the server crashes the picture is still there. In my case its not true indication of servers state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is supported by WebSockets, https://www.google.com/search?q=websockets. 
You'll have to update your javascript, assuming your browser supports it, and then update your servlet code, and container to support. Jetty supports it, I'm not sure about the other containers.

Or alternatively, you could save your progress to a table or something and poll that data.

Comment: I wouldn't want to use a table simple because it will add to complexity and further add overhead to my actual task.

Havent used websockets - this looks promising. will update if this solves my problem.

Comment: I have used WebSockets finally and the implementation(not best solution but) works well for me. Thanks Sumit.

Answer (score 0):

With the first request you could show a page with some kind of "please wait" indicator and do a second request that actually fetches the data (eg. via JavaScript).

Comment: Updated question Henry.

Answer (score 0):

Show a loading bar using javascript . This would tell the user that something is happening in the background .

Comment: I am already doing that Shuhail .. Sorry forgot to mention updated my question.

I am using JS to display a picture that says loading while my servlet is processing data. However even if servlet gets stuck or crashes, this GIF is still running. I tried crashing my system.

I would prefer If i could actually print server names and if their result is processed - slightly more informative.